# Read more/read less script working in different text types

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-lists

I have an e-commerce with several types of descriptions, they can be paragraphs, unordered lists, or ordered lists. I use a script for the see more/see less function that I have been able to get to work correctly depending on the number of paragraphs and their length. But there are situations where the text is just a list, and for these cases, I can't find a way to make the script work correctly. In the html example, the last  contains only a list with no paragraphs after it, the script doesn't work. What is the mistake?

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.description').each(function(){
var p = $(this).find('p, ul, ol');
var LiN = p.length;
if( LiN > 3){
$(p).eq(2).nextAll().hide().addClass('toggleable');
$(this).find('p, ul, ol').eq(4).nextAll().hide().addClass('toggleable');
$(this).append('<p class="more">Read more...</p>');
}
});

$('.description').on('click','.more', function(){
if( $(this).hasClass('less') ){
$(this).text('Read more...').removeClass('less');
}else{
$(this).text('Read less...').addClass('less');
}
$(this).siblings('p.toggleable, ul.toggleable, ol.toggeable').slideToggle();
});
});
```

```css
.more{color:red; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
  <p>Párrafo 01</p>
    <p>Párrafo 02</p>
    <p>Párrafo 02</p>
    <p>Párrafo 04</p>
    <p>Párrafo 05</p>
    <p>Párrafo 06</p>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <ul>
<li>Lista 01</li>
<li>Lista 02</li>
<li>Lista 03</li>
<li>Lista 04</li>
<li>Lista 05</li>
<li>Lista 06</li>
 </ul>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
</div>


<div class="description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <ol>
<li>Lista 01</li>
<li>Lista 02</li>
<li>Lista 03</li>
<li>Lista 04</li>
<li>Lista 05</li>
<li>Lista 06</li>
 </ol>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>

</div>


<div class="description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <ul>
<li>Lista 01</li>
<li>Lista 02</li>
<li>Lista 03</li>
<li>Lista 04</li>
<li>Lista 05</li>
<li>Lista 06</li>
<li>Lista 07</li>
<li>Lista 08</li>
<li>Lista 09</li>
<li>Lista 10</li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Last div doesn't have description class

Comment: Sorry, fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give common class to all your elements and then use that class and [:gt()](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) to hide or show the required elements .

**Demo Code** :

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".description").find('p, ul > li, ol > li').addClass("elements"); //add this class to all elements///
  $('.description').each(function() {
    var p = $(this).find('.elements');
    var LiN = p.length;
    if (LiN > 3) {
      $(this).find('.elements:gt(2)').hide().addClass('toggleable'); //hide all elements which is > 2
      $(this).append('<p class="more">Read more...</p>');
    }
  });

  $('.description').on('click', '.more', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('less')) {
      $(this).text('Read more...').removeClass('less');
    } else {
      $(this).text('Read less...').addClass('less');
    }
    $(this).closest(".description").find(".elements.toggleable").slideToggle(); //use class to hide
  });

});
```

```css
.more {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
  <p>Párrafo 01</p>
  <p>Párrafo 02</p>
  <p>Párrafo 02</p>
  <p>Párrafo 04</p>
  <p>Párrafo 05</p>
  <p>Párrafo 06</p>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lista 01</li>
    <li>Lista 02</li>
    <li>Lista 03</li>
    <li>Lista 04</li>
    <li>Lista 05</li>
    <li>Lista 06</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
</div>


<div class="description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <ol>
    <li>Lista 01</li>
    <li>Lista 02</li>
    <li>Lista 03</li>
    <li>Lista 04</li>
    <li>Lista 05</li>
    <li>Lista 06</li>
  </ol>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>

  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>

  <ol>
    <li>Lista 07</li>
    <li>Lista 08</li>
    <li>Lista 09</li>
    <li>Lista 010</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div class="description">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Lista 01</li>
    <li>Lista 02</li>
    <li>Lista 03</li>
    <li>Lista 04</li>
    <li>Lista 05</li>
    <li>Lista 06</li>
    <li>Lista 07</li>
    <li>Lista 08</li>
    <li>Lista 09</li>
    <li>Lista 10</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. I need to study this in detail 